# Will Spring creates a bean using @DependsOn after @PostConstruct of other bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

We have 4 Beans BeanA, BeanB, BeanC, BeanD
We have a cache in BeanA which gets filled in the @PostConstruct of BeanA.
Now, BeanB also have a cache which gets filled in the @PostConstruct of BeanB.

BeanB's cache depends on the BeanA's cache. So BeanB should be created only after successfully creation of BeanA and BeanA's cache.

Can we ensure this using @DependsOn?
What role does @PostContruct performs? When we say BeanA is succesfully created do we mean it's @PostConstruct has been completed successfully?

If not @DependsOn is there any other way to ensure this.

```
public class BeanA {
  private ConcurrentCache<> cacheA;

  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
   cache = fillingCache();
  }
}
```

```
public class BeanB {
  private ConcurrentCache<> cacheB;

  @Autowired
  private BeanA beanA;

  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
   cacheB = beanA.cacheA;
  }
}
```

Comment: No. You can't rely on `@DependsOn` for `@PostContruct` methods. `@DependsOn` only affects beans instantiation order.

Comment: Is there any other way to ensure this?

Comment: It depends on when the cache will really be utilized ... but maybe you could create a third service (prototype'd with the `ApplicationRunner` interface) that takes your beans as dependencies and coordinates the cache assignments? I don't know for sure, but I suspect the `run()` method would only be called after the `@PostConstruct` of its dependencies (your cache services).

Comment: The idea is that if cache is not filled then don't create the bean and break the server startup so that it should not receive any request.
Caching makes a call to 3rd party APIs to get the data.

Comment: Lots of things you can do. Pub/Sub Spring application event. Any java sync mechanism: latch/exchanger... or even have a third component which coordinate the other two